# How to read a local server JSON file with react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I need to read a JSON file located on my machine with my react application and nothing seem to work.

I tried importing **fs** (with import and require) but it returns a blank object and I cannot use any of it's functions.

Jquery doesn't seem to find my file either.

Everywhere I searched they use FS, Jquery or FileReader (the last one is always used for files that the client uploaded to the page).

This is one of the solutions I tried with FS:

```
const fs = require("fs");

export default function getJson() {
  let rawdata = fs.readFile("file.json");
  let json = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  console.log(json);
}
```

When I reload the browser

```
TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
```

With Jquery I tried this:

```
import $ from "jquery";

export default function getJson() {
  $.getJSON("file.json", function() {
    console.log("success");
  });
}
```

The console shows this:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs` is an inrospection that connects Node's engine to the underlying OS. It does not exist in browser code (e.g. ReactJS).

For security measures, browsers deny JS from interacting with the underlying platform. So to read the file, you have two option (as far as I know):

Either create a file-input field in html (like the file-upload fields you usually see). Or you need to serve the file by some server. You can put the file in your `assets` folder, and then request it in react.

Update 1:
From my experience, one of the easier ways to include a "runtime-configuration" is to serve the configuration as an asset.
I don't have much experience in ReactJS, but the idea is the same.
Let's say you put the `config.json` in `Public/json/config.json`. Then you can read this file from the application by requesting it.

here's an example:

```
fetch("/json/config.json").then(resp=>resp.json()).then(console.log);
```

and here's a small working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-umxktz)

Comment: If I create the file-input field could I pass it my local file automatically from the server (my machine)?

Comment: No. The user must browse the file system and select the file to be used. I believe you need to serve the file in the assets directory.
Edit: It's actualy called "Public" directory in react

Comment: What I want to use is my own file that is located in my project. I don't want the user to upload anything. 
Should I put my json on the public directory to have access to it?

Comment: Give a few minutes to create another answer if I may. I'll try to be detailed as possible.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much!